# Phone connected as an emulator to android studio and showing error when running flutter project via phone

Tags: flutter, dart, android-emulator

I created new flutter project. And connect my phone as an emulator to Android Studio.

When I tried to run that project without changing anything inside, it showed in console this error:

```
**[Fatal Error] kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] x86_debug-1.0.0-2a3401c9bbb5a9a9aec74d4f735d18a9dd3ebf2d.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-2a3401c9bbb5a9a9aec74d4f735d18a9dd3ebf2d.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-2a3401c9bbb5a9a9aec74d4f735d18a9dd3ebf2d.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-2a3401c9bbb5a9a9aec74d4f735d18a9dd3ebf2d.
         > Could not parse POM https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_debug/1.0.0-2a3401c9bbb5a9a9aec74d4f735d18a9dd3ebf2d/flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-2a3401c9bbb5a9a9aec74d4f735d18a9dd3ebf2d.pom
            > Content is not allowed in prolog.
   > Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_debug:1.0.0-2a3401c9bbb5a9a9aec74d4f735d18a9dd3ebf2d.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_debug:1.0.0-2a3401c9bbb5a9a9aec74d4f735d18a9dd3ebf2d.
         > Could not parse POM https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-2a3401c9bbb5a9a9aec74d4f735d18a9dd3ebf2d/x86_debug-1.0.0-2a3401c9bbb5a9a9aec74d4f735d18a9dd3ebf2d.pom
            > Content is not allowed in prolog.
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10.
         > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.7.10/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10.pom
            > Content is not allowed in prolog.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 27s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1**
```

In case if you need project:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

But when I tried to run the project using Chrome (web), it worked perfectly. When it comes to emulator it's showing that error, written above.

I researched in google and find some similar errors but not identical. Although, I tried them but nothing is changed, still the same error.